# Multiple cors origins on AWS API gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I there a way on setting multiple origins on AWS API gateway. I went through documentation and you can set only one origin for CORS.

Comment: You can add multiple origins comma-spaced in double quotes or use a "*" wildcard too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we can only set one origin(or the wildcard) in **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header. This is not a limitation of Aws API Gateway, this is just standard that Browser understands irrespective of which server/gateway.

We can always check incoming **origin** header from the request and if it is found in our list of valid headers, we can respond origin header value back in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.